# $[K(\mathbb Z,4),\mathbb H\text{P}^{\infty}]$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

The map $\mathbb H\text{P}^{\infty} \to K(\mathbb Z,4)$ representing a generator of $H^4(\mathbb H\text{P}^{\infty};\mathbb Z) = \mathbb Z$ is a rational equivalence.

But is there any honest map in the other direction (before rationalizing, of course) that is not null-homotopic?

And if so, how can we understand the set of all homotopy classes $[K(\mathbb Z,4),\mathbb H\text{P}^{\infty}]$?

Comment: Note that $\Omega$ of such a map would be a map $K(\mathbb{Z},3)\rightarrow S^3$, which I think is nullhomotopic, so if there is a nontrivial map like you want it'd act trivially on  $\pi_4$, $H^4$ and so all cohomology.

Comment: Yes, according to a theorem of Zabrodsky, using Miller's theorem resolving the Sullivan conjecture, every map $K(\mathbb{Z}, 3) \to S^3$ must be a phantom map; but since there is no pair of dimensions $n$ and $n+1$ for which the rational cohomology of the domain is nontrivial in dimension $n$ and the rational homotopy of the target is nontrivial in dimension $n+1$, the only phantom map available is the trivial map.

Comment: In "Connective Coverings, Phantom Maps and Genus Sets" by McGibbon and Roitberg they construct a pair of rational equivalences $S^{4n-1}\rightarrow S^{2n}\langle 2n\rangle \rightarrow K(\mathbb{Z},4n-1)$ and show there are no maps in the opposite direction which become rational inverses. Perhaps their methods may be of interest.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but a pointed map $K(\mathbb{Z}, 4) \to \mathbb{HP}^\infty$ should be equivalent to an $E_4$-map $\mathbb{Z} \to \Omega^3S^3$.

Comment: An honest map from K(Z,4)  must induce 0 in integral cohomology.  This is because there are mod p primary cohomology operations of odd degree acting nontrivially  on the mod p reductions of the fundamental class in K(Z,4), for all primes p.  Thus an honest map is zero in dimension 4, hence 0 in all positive dimensions of the polynomial algebra. John R. Harper.